# How is a keyboard responsive web application built?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, keyboard

I ran across a touch typing tutorial website named keybr.com

This web application feels like a desktop application. The site is able to read keyboard input in real time.

My question is how could you accomplish this in an ASP.net application? My guess is that you would use a Javascript library like JQuery.

I'm a backfire developer who is learning the world of web development.

Thanks,

Comment: Native JavaScript has keyboard event listeners, you don't need a libary for them.

Comment: I was overthinking this of course. I now realize that JavaScript can do this without the need for a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jquery you can bind keyup and keypress events to any element.

https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

You could also bind them to the whole document.

```
$(document.body).bind("keyup", function(e){

alert(e.which)
// do something
})
```

This would throw the keycode of the pressed key.

Answer (score 2):

I guess on overall you are looking for accessibility. Like mentioned in the previous answer `key` events will give you the keycode and you can design accordingly.

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) you can find all keycodes.

Along with this there is a HTML attribute called `tabIndex`. In a web page you may have buttons ,content area,dropdown and you have to navigate among these components. So in those cases you have to use tabIndex.

For example

```
 // From w3school

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" tabindex="2">W3Schools</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" tabindex="1">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/" tabindex="3">Microsoft</a>
```

Elements can have positive & negative tabIndex, negative that is `tabIndex ="-1"` is used when you want to remove it from navigation flow.

Elements with positive & identical tabIndex will be navigated in order they appear.So first all elements with `tabIndex="1"` will be navigated followed by elements with `tabIndex="2"` and so on.

Beside there is another atribute called `ARIA`, which can also help you. You can explore more 
[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA).

Hope this will be helpful to you